# VB.NET Windows Service not working with MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, windows-services

I'm creating a windows service with a timer that will tick every few seconds and then query a database. The timer for the service works fine, but as soon as I add any of the MySql details it stops working.

Just adding the few lines below stops it from working

```
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=localhost;User ID=root;Password=******;database=******;"
    Dim sqlConn As MySqlConnection
    sqlConn = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
```

Without these lines the timer keeps on ticking (I am writing to the `EventLog` to see what is happening)

I thought it may have been a referencing problem but I have added the `MySql.Data` reference.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT:
Entire method added as requested

```
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Service1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        serviceTimer.Enabled = True
        serviceTimer.Start()
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService Started and Timer started")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        serviceTimer.Stop()
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Out OnStop", EventLogEntryType.Information)
    End Sub

    Private Sub serviceTimer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles serviceTimer.Elapsed
        Dim MyLog As New EventLog()

        If Not EventLog.SourceExists("MyService") Then
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyService", "Myservice Log")
        End If
        MyLog.Source = "MyService"
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService Log", "This is log on " & CStr(TimeOfDay), EventLogEntryType.Information)

        Dim ConnectionString As String = "Data Source=localhost;User ID=root;Password=******;database=******;"

        Using sqlConn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
            Dim sqlComm As MySqlCommand
            Dim outputParam As Integer
            sqlConn.Open()
            sqlComm = New MySqlCommand("uspTest", sqlConn)
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlComm.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("Test", "100"))
            outputParam = CInt(sqlComm.ExecuteScalar)
            sqlConn.Close()
        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you post the entire method please? It may be related to something that happens before or after the creation of the MySqlConnection. I would also write your block as Using sqlConn as new MySqlConnection(connectionString) ... End Using just to make sure the object is disposed every tick.

Comment: I'm currently testing it by installing it and running it as a windows service, the service doesn't throw exceptions (i don't think) so I don't have a specific exception. Do you know a way of getting exceptions from a windows service? Or a better way of testing it

Comment: Also, try using the following connection string: "Persist Security Info=False;database=*****;server=localhost;user id=root;pwd=*****". I've never used Data Source with a MySql connection.

Comment: The easiest way to test this is to extract all of the code you want the service to run into it's own project. You can then reference this code in the Windows Service, and also in a Windows Form or Console Application or whatever, making it simple to step into and debug.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I tried it with the altered `ConnectionString` but it didn't make any difference. Looks like I'm going to have to try and run it in its own project and see what's wrong

Comment: What type of timer are you using, and what is the interval? Are you seeing the event written to the event log?

Comment: I only posted up the first part of the code, as all the code behind it wasn't running either, have just edited showing that its just a standard MySql connection

Comment: It could also be related to the service not having permission to write to the event log. If you move the code out into a separate library and just call it from a console app or GUI app then you'll find it in no time.

Comment: I managed to fix it, turns out i hadn't installed the MySql to Net Connector on my Server so it wasn't working! Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the above code was correct, I had forgotten to install the MySQL/NET Connector on my Server, i had installed it on my PC but had forgotten to install it on my Server!